# How to disable the mousewheel scroll interaction in Iframe

Tags: iframe, archilogic

I’m a developer working on integrating Archilogic content (Iframe embeds only, for now) into my WordPress plugin.

We present the content at full width of the window, but with the ability to supplement additional content below. This full-width presentation method can sometimes create issues for users when a browser window is positioned such that interactive content fills the entire viewport. When this is the case, it isn’t possible for them to scroll/swipe down the page, past the ‘running’ model.

Is it possible (through a URL parameter) to disable the ‘mousewheel’ interaction on a particular embed?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

One way you could achieve this is by positioning a transparent  overlay on top of the iframe, and when the user actively tries to interact with the iframe (for example by click), only then would you allow the mouse events to go through to the iframe.

The mask could be as simple as

```
<div onclick="style.pointerEvents='none'"></div>
```

It will block the mousewheel events until it has been clicked.

There's also the url parameter for archilogic models `autostart=false` which pauses the model until you hit play

Comment: I'm afraid this method doesn't really solve the issue that's being described.  Once an archilogic model is "running" you can still (on a growing number of devices, especially those running iOS) become "stuck" inside.  In these cases, there becomes no way to access a parent window's scrollbars in order to move past the interactive content and on to the rest of the page in which the <iframe> is embedded.

Comment: Note that this same issue was present with Matterport embeds, but was remedied perfectly with their "wh=0" parameter.  

They describe the functionality as follows:

Ignore scroll wheel input from the mouse. Scroll wheel input will cause the entire webpage to move up and down. This parameter is only valid when the Space is embedded with an iframe.

Fingers crossed that Archilogic will consider a similar option.

Comment: You’re completely right, it’s not a great solution for a few reasons. I’m not sure about the status of a url parameter, but Archilogic is in the process of open sourcing its front end... so modifications like this will soon be very possible

Comment: Thanks Benjamin...any idea on a timeline for this conversion to an open source front end, for Archilogic?

Comment: It's in the very near future as there is already a functioning beta. Here is the space to watch: https://3d.io.